# Wordpress template doesn't find php file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, forms, templates

I am creating a template page in Wordpress that contains a custom contact form in it, using php and ajax.

I have two files in the same directory:

wp-content/themes/verbo/template01.php (contact form) and wp-content/themes/verbo/sendEmail.php (ajax)

In template01.php I have the ajax request like this:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "sendEmail.php", true);
```

However, that line is giving me an error:
"failed to load resource server responded with status 404"

template01.php and sendEmail.php are in the same directory, so the problem is not in the reference, I think. I even tried with absolute references, but the result is the same.

This form works on my localserver. Just not as a Wordpress template.

I was having the same problem with my styles.css. After googling it a bit, I solved it by replacing `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">` with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/style.css" media="screen">`.

So, I guess the problem lies with how wordpress handles these things.

I am not very experienced with wordpress so, any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not how ajax works for WordPress, you can make it work but you'll probably find some hurdles, follow instructions here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: This is not the way to call any AJAX functions in WordPress. Please read the given link by Ali_K. In Theme the process is same as that.